# Passing rules to make recursively

Tags: recursion, makefile

It's probably trivial to do this but I can't see how.

I want to have a parent Makefile to decide which Makefile to call recursively based on the value of a variable passed in the command line.

I.e., I want to be able to call my main Makefile with:

```
make some_rule TARGET=a
```

or

```
make some_rule TARGET=b
```

and have my main Makefile decide based on the value of TARGET which makefile to invoke to run make some_rule.  (For example, decide whether to call sub_directory_a/Makefile or sub_directory_b/Makefile to execute rule some_rule.)

Note: I have many different rules, so I do not want my main Makefile to list all the possible rules and for each of them call recursively the correct Makefile.  I am hoping my main Makefile can only be a few lines long and not have to be updated whenever I create new rules.

Comment: I think http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/multi-architecture-builds/ might be of some use to you here. That being said do you expect your toplevel makefile to be doing anything for you or just choosing the right sub-folder to invoke make in? Because if it isn't doing anything for you then perhaps just using `make -C sub_directory_a` is the right idea.

Comment: Well, it's a good idea but yes, I would like to use my main make to set variables that will be shared by all the other makefiles.

Comment: One way to resolve my problem simply would be if there was a way to tell make to run the same rule no matter what rule is requested by the user.  I.e. whether I call make rule_1 or make rule_2, the main make would execute the same rule internally, setting whatever variables I need to be set and deciding which makefile to invoke and passing on the rule provided by the user. I do not know if that's possible but that would solve what I am after.

Comment: Building on what I just said, perhaps I should just list explicitly all the rules supported by all my specialized makefiles in the common make and call the same 'default' target. That should work and it isn't the end of the world if I have to just list all the supported rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do what you describe with

```
default_target:

%:
    $(MAKE) -C some_directory_$(TARGET) $@
```

The `%:` rule is a pattern rule in which the pattern matches all rules (called a match-anything rule by the GNU make manual); `$@` is the current target. Note that the `default_target:` rule doesn't have a recipe, so calling `make` without a target will use the recipe of the match-anything rule (the only one that applies and has a recipe) to try to build `default_target`.

The caveat of this approach is that targets cannot be declared phony. If you want to have phony targets, you'll have to specify the recipe for those targets again, for example

```
PHONY_TARGETS = all clean distclean

.PHONY: $(PHONY_TARGETS)

$(PHONY_TARGETS):
    $(MAKE) -C some_directory_$(TARGET) $@

%:
    $(MAKE) -C some_directory_$(TARGET) $@
```

Unfortunately, I do not know a trick to declare all targets phony, which is what you'd really want to do.

Note that you can use `ifeq` etc. with the variables you set at the command line if you want to allow more fancy values for `TARGET` than parts of directory names, such as

```
%:
ifeq ($(TARGET),gibson)
    echo 'Planet $@ was successfully hacked.'
else
    $(MAKE) -C some_directory_$(TARGET) $@
endif
```

Also note that a more common way to set common variables for many Makefiles is to put them into a file, often `common.mk`, and `include` it from the other Makefiles:

```
include ../common.mk    # to include common.mk from some_directory_a/Makefile
```

But you'll have to decide yourself which approach is a better fit for your project.

Comment: I wished I could mark your answer as the correct one twice, because not only you answered my question but you also answered the next one I was about to ask: how to declare variables in a separate file that multiple makefiles can share. This is great. Thank you!